# change style of all sibling element when hover?

Tags: html, css

This is my snippet:

```html
<div class="main">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
        a
    </a>

    <a href="" target="_blank">
        b
    </a>

    <a href="" target="_blank">
        c
    </a>

    <a href="" target="_blank">
        d
    </a>
</div>

<style>
.main a {
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.main a:hover {
    
}
</style>
```

I want to change the opacity to `.5` of all the blue when i hovering each box, the result would be like this 
[image]

is this possible with css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. I've added the style below. You can see it working on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/JordanRolph/pen/MWaqaOX?editors=1010). It relies on detecting hover on the parent, as well as the individual child.

If you plan on putting more content in `main`, you could wrap the `a` tags in a `div`, then target `div:hover` instead.

```
<div class="main">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
        a
    </a>

    <a href="" target="_blank">
        b
    </a>

    <a href="" target="_blank">
        c
    </a>

    <a href="" target="_blank">
        d
    </a>
</div>

<style>
.main a {
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.main:hover a {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.main:hover a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are only the objects you want to add this effect to in the main Element, I would try something like this:

```
.main:hover a { opacity: 0.5 }
```

and the selected element:

```
.main:hover a:hover { opacity: 1}
```

This should create the effect that you would like to achieve.